# По какой причине удаляются куки раньше чем задано?

Tags: javascript, cookie

Вчера задавал вот это [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1196338/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-js-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B) и заметил что куки удаляются браузером намного раньше чем заложено.

### Вот код добавления куки:

```
if (theme_click == "dark"){                                     // Проверяет какое значение получает theme_click
    let date = new Date(Date.now()); // Получение сегодняшней даты
    date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear + 12); // Прибавляет 12 лет к сроку годности куки
    date = date.toUTCString(); // Переводит в нужный формат
    document.cookie = "theme=lite; path=/; expires="+date; // Передаёт нужные куки, которые должны действовать 12 лет, но на деле ничего не работает. Таже передаёт theme=lite
// Дальше тоже самое, но если нету куки с name == theme или для lite и устанавливает dark
    
}else{
   let date = new Date(Date.now());
   date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear + 12);
   date = date.toUTCString();
   document.cookie = "theme=dark; path=/; expires="+date;
};
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему они удаляются раньше времени? И как правильно написать расчёт даты, чтобы всё было хорошо?

PS: Сайт размещён на github.io, может потому удаляются куки?-_-

Comment: Влажненько) Куки у вас ставятся на время жизни сессии

Comment: Не проще использовать LocalStorage?

Comment: @SDarkness, что это? Я просто первый раз с печеньками работаю)

Comment: DGDays, тоже самое, только не нужно ставить время и не отправляет на хост.

Comment: Такс, а вот это интересно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

date.getFullYear — функция, её нужно вызывать

```
let date = new Date();
date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 12);
date = date.toGMTString();

// let new_theme = theme_click == "dark" ? "lite" : "dark";
// document.cookie = `theme=${new_theme}; path=/; expires=${date}`;

if (theme_click == "dark"){
    document.cookie = "theme=lite; path=/; expires="+date;
}else{
    document.cookie = "theme=dark; path=/; expires="+date;
};
```

Comment: Ну, вроде и функция, но у меня консоль материлась на вызов Потому и сделал так. Ща попробуем)